# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'maintitle'

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [maintitle] => EMS Почта России
            [description] => </br><span style="font-size:10px;">EMS Почта России (быстрая доставка курьерской службой)</span>
        )

    [quote] => Array
        (
            [ems_standart] => Array
                (
                    [code] => ems.ems_standart
                    [title] => Доставка EMS
                    [description] => <span style="font-size:10px; color: #555" colspan="3">Ростов-На-Дону - Барнаул</br>Вес: 25,00г (+50,00г за упаковку)</br>Доставка за: 4 - 5 день/дней (+1 день/дней на подготовку заказа)</br>Цена: 610 р. (+100 р. дополнительно)</span>
                    [cost] => 710
                    [tax_class_id] => 0
                    [text] => 710 р.
                )

            [ems_importance] => Array
                (
                    [code] => ems.ems_importance
                    [title] => Доставка EMS <b>(с объявленной ценностью 1%)</b>
                    [description] => <span style="font-size:10px; color: #555" colspan="3">Ростов-На-Дону - Барнаул</br>Вес: 25,00г (+50,00г за упаковку)</br>Доставка за: 4 - 5 день/дней (+1 день/дней на подготовку заказа)</br>Цена: 616 р. (+100 р. дополнительно)</span>
                    [cost] => 716.1
                    [tax_class_id] => 0
                    [text] => 716 р.
                )

        )

    [sort_order] => 3
    [error] => 
)
```

В php файле выводится maintitle следующим образом:

```
<?php echo $shipping_method['title']['maintitle']; ?>
```

На странице maintitle выводится правильно, но в логах выдаётся ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'maintitle' in shipping_method.tpl on line 12
```

Вот полный код, содержащий вывод из массива:

```
  <?php foreach ($shipping_methods as $shipping_method) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><b><?php echo $shipping_method['title']['maintitle']; ?></b></td>
  </tr>
  <?php if (!$shipping_method['error']) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td><?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
      <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
      <?php } else { ?>
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" />
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['title']; ?></label></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['text']; ?></label></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div class="error"><?php echo $shipping_method['error']; ?></div></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Нет ли еще обращений к массиву $shipping_method? Возможно где-то еще есть обращение к $shipping_method['title']['maintitle'] в момент, когда массив не заполнен или заполнен не полностью?

Comment: добавил в конец сообщения весь промежуток кода, где тем или иным образом обрабатывается $shipping_method

Comment: Пробовали сделать print_r($shipping_methods) перед первым foreach из топика? Возможно криво сформирован сам массив?